# Information about ffmpeg what algorithm does it use if any

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm in search of some info about FFmpeg.I did search for the info but did not find answers for most of my questions.

FFmpeg is a framework written in C++ which helps in editing videos from the command line.
So what does FFmpeg use to do editing like are there any algorithms which it uses or any? 
If I'm building a project then I can say the project comes under image processing as a video is made up of images and the framework works on images right? 
or video processing? 
FFmpeg is a stand-alone framework right or it depends on any other? 
Sorry for asking noncoding questions here

Answer (score 1):

FFmpeg is a multimedia decoding/encoding/... library and suite of applications.

It is capable of (de)muxing, de/encoding, transcoding, rendering to screen, and even employs hardware features to do all of these things if possible/available.

Depending on the files involved, it uses various other libraries to extract information and data from the multimedia files, and sometimes has its own code to do these things. When reading, writing, decoding or encoding video, many different algorithms are used, mostly dependent on the actual video and audio formats involved, as they usually describe the compression algorithm you have to use and even what parameters these algorithms must use in specific situations (e.g. a Level 4 H.264 video uses a fixed set of parameters to ensure decoders can always decode these types of videos).

Video is more than just a bunch of images. Eventually each frame will be blitted to your screen in quick succession, but the files themselves definitely do not contain these images directly.

Comment: Thanks for the response can u please provide some reference for algorithms which it uses if any available.                                                                                                                
 Then the project comes under video processing, right?                      
    To be specific I'm building a video editor with some functionalities which are not available in most the video editors

Comment: Now that you mention it, it can also do some processing (e.g. scaling) but it is focused on decoding and encoding. I'm not sure what you mean by algorithms here exactly. The decode/encode algorithms are described in the format's standards, but other than the basics (like reframes etc.) a video editor shouldn't need to care all too much. If you want more detailed help, It would be best to try and ask the FFmpeg community (see their mailing lists here: https://ffmpeg.org/mailman/listinfo). You'll want to ask on ffmpeg-user or libav-user depending on what part of their code you are interested in.